# What are relevant Posts from other SE sites or SO or other resource which we can use as a resource to improve this site

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

There would be a wealth of information in other sites in the network which might be of interest to users of Bu.SE wirht regard to:

- policies
- resources / tips to improve the content
- ways to improve visits
- food for thought

What might the resources that are available on other sites which we can use to improve to site, or be resources to help users improve their contribution?